# How to write and check cookie in Dot Net Core

Tags: c#, cookies, .net-core

I'm trying to create a basic cookie and check that it's available in my code but it doesn't work and I suspect I am missing something obvious.

```
private JwtSecurityToken GetJsonWebTokenFromCookie()
{
    var personId = 0;
    var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken();

#if DEBUG

    Response.Cookies.Append(".FAPPSOUSR", "pid=48527257", new CookieOptions
    {
        Domain = "localhost",
        Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
        Path = "/",
    });

#endif

    var cookieValueFromContext = HttpContext.Request.Cookies[".FAPPSOUSR"];

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookieValueFromContext)) return null;

    if (Request.Cookies["pid"] != null)
    {
        var value = Request.Cookies["pid"];
        int.TryParse(value, out personId);
        if (personId == 0) return null;
    }

    jwt.Claims.Append(new Claim("nameid", personId.ToString()));
    return jwt;
}
```

This is always null:

```
var cookieValueFromContext = HttpContext.Request.Cookies[".FAPPSOUSR"];
```

Comment: Is the cookie actually set?

Answer (score 0):

I have written wrapper on top of http cookie which helps to ease of use. it has silent features.

- Strongly Typed
- Securing Cookie Data to protect
- Easy options to configure CookieManager
- Ease to use

try out [here](https://github.com/nemi-chand/CookieManager)

add the CookieManager in configure service in start up class

```
//add CookieManager
services.AddCookieManager();
```

getting the Cookie object

```
MyCookie objFromCookie = _cookieManager.Get<MyCookie>("Key");
```

set the Cookie object

```
_cookieManager.Set("Key", cooObj, 60);
```

hope it helps you